# Unit Test Cases for Services Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm

I have a Web Application in grails, The Groovy services are used to access database. Needs to create the test case for the various methods. Using the approach below always getting the NullPointerException generated when the service method is called from Unit test case.
The issue is in accessing the database connection. Please suggest.

**Just to add i run the unit test case after executing the application.

TestService.groovy

```
package com.sample.services

import com.gmongo.GMongo
import com.mongodb.DB
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class TestService {
    GMongo mongo
    DB db

    def DB db() {
        return mongo.getDB("myApp")
    }

    def getDistinctProducts() {
        return db().app_products.distinct("products").sort()
    }
}
```

Unit test case

```
package com.sample.services

import grails.test.GrailsMock
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(TestService)
class TestServiceSpec extends Specification {

    void "test get distinct products"() {
          def str   
          when:
             str = service.getDistinctProducts()
          then:
             str.size() == 36  
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't test persistence with unit tests - use integration or functional tests.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Is it not possible or not feasible, can you please elaborate a bit.